# Is there a shortcut to insert current datetime as a static value in a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like this:

| Expense | Date | What it was for |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 120 CZK | 4.5.2021. 12:30 | Pizza coz I'm lazy |

I use it to log some expenses, not exactly for pizza but that's just an example. I also have similar tables where I really NEED both date and time.

I found out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> inserts current date, but without time. Is there also a shortcut for both date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut for "insert date and time" is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>.

See the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that if I kept mashing random keys, the sheet offered some help dialog with all shortcuts. In the dialog was the answer to my question.

To insert both date and time, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: You probably hit the **Ctrl + /** shortcut that shows common keyboard shortcuts. Refer to the [keyboard shortcuts](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=spreadsheets_shortcuts&answer=181110) help page to see them all.